# Statements order in Node js

Tags: node.js

new to Node JS, still getting used to the way things are done.
I am processing a file with this structure:

```
[1447113604] [104] [86]
[1447113605] [111] [91]
[1447113606] [127] [114]
[1447113607] [115] [105]
[1447113608] [120] [101]
[1447113609] [105] [100]
[1447113610] [89] [88]
```

I read it line by line,parse each line and create and object that has 3 properties (timestamp, count1, count2), then I add the newly created object to an array, at the end I want to loop through the array and print its elements with a for loop.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var arr_counters = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({        
      input : fs.createReadStream("cps.log"),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false    
})

rl.on('line',function(line){
    console.log(line) //or parse line
    var tokens = line.split(" ");

  var str_TS = tokens[0].substring(1,11);   //strip '[' ']'
  var int_p = tokens[1].substring(1, tokens[1].length - 1); //strip '[' ']'
  var int_c = tokens[2].substring(1, tokens[2].length - 1);//strip '[' ']'

    console.log(str_TS.toString());
    console.log(int_p.toString());
    console.log(int_c.toString());

    var counter = {
        timestamp: parseInt(str_TS),
        PCount: parseInt(int_p),
        CCount: parseInt(int_c)
    }
    arr_counters.push(counter);
})

for (var index = 0; index < arr_counters.length; index++)
    console.log(arr_counters[index]);
```

But the last 2 lines seemed to be skipped, I can't see the elements of the array:
This is the current output:

```
E:\Node-JS>node read_file2.js
[1447113604] [104] [86]
1447113604
104
86
[1447113605] [111] [91]
1447113605
111
91
[1447113606] [127] [114]
1447113606
127
114
[1447113607] [115] [105]
1447113607
115
105
[1447113608] [120] [101]
1447113608
120
101
[1447113609] [105] [100]
1447113609
105
100
```

If I place the for loop right after pushing the object in the array then I see them as they are added on each iteration, the question is how can I access the array properly after it has been filled with the objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your loop is running before your readLine is finished parsing. You need to call your loop only once the entire file is parsed via its `close` event.

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var arr_counters = [];

var rl = readline.createInterface({        
      input : fs.createReadStream("cps.log"),
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false    
})

rl.on('line',function(line){
    console.log(line) //or parse line
    var tokens = line.split(" ");

  var str_TS = tokens[0].substring(1,11);   //strip '[' ']'
  var int_p = tokens[1].substring(1, tokens[1].length - 1); //strip '[' ']'
  var int_c = tokens[2].substring(1, tokens[2].length - 1);//strip '[' ']'

    console.log(str_TS.toString());
    console.log(int_p.toString());
    console.log(int_c.toString());

    var counter = {
        timestamp: parseInt(str_TS),
        PCount: parseInt(int_p),
        CCount: parseInt(int_c)
    }
    arr_counters.push(counter);
})


rl.on('close',function(){
    for (var index = 0; index < arr_counters.length; index++)
        console.log(arr_counters[index]);
});
```